# Sharepoint : I am trying to share a link with some users and i am using library @pnp/sp/sharing

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I have the below error :

Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.InvalidOperationException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Sharing by link is not enabled on the web, site, or tenant."}}}
    at new HttpRequestError (parsers.ts:13)
    at parsers.ts:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your site collection enable sharing in tenant settings.

https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot I found the same solution yesterday ;D